# HUGE fluctuations in PageSpeed results making it hard to correct errors

Tags: google-pagespeed

The home page speed is great at 93 and in the green. PageSpeed Insights has worked incredibly well making some changes to increase speed. But right now I am stumped.

I am working on increasing speed on several interior pages. 
I run PageSpeed Insights and get a score of 82
https://www.crevand.com/boise/
Now I run it again and again...
15 seconds later - 83
15 seconds later - 78
15 seconds later - 85
15 seconds later - 82

For kicks... I run this on a large national site https://www.espn.com/ Result= 13
15 seconds later - 14
15 seconds later - 18
15 seconds later - 16
15 seconds later - 15

Just as volatile. Does this mean this up/down is a PageSpeed insights issue? Would I achieve far greater accuracy if I ran this late in the evening or early in the morning?

How am I supposed to determine if the suggested edits are positive or negative for increasing speed if I cannot get a solid result? Does anyone else have this problem?

Is this a result of fluctuations with my server? Fluctuation on the PageSpeed insights server load? I am so frustrated right now!

Comment: "How am I supposed to determine if the suggested edits are positive or negative" - take N samples, then use the average or median.  Make a change.  take N new samples.  You can see if this works for youi by deliberately making a bad change.  The higher N is set the more reliable this should be, but diminishing returns sets in if you make N larger than needed.

Comment: Hi Crevand, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not contain anything we can help you with so I have voted to close it. All I will say is ignore the 'score' at the top just focus on the suggestions on what to fix. Anything above 80 is fine, the effort in improving beyond this is not worth it unless you are turning over £1,000,000. For more accurate results use the audits tab in google chrome and set the throttling to 'applied slow 4G, 4x CPU Slowdown' as the varience comes in simulating latency on a normal page speed load rather than actually throttling the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Page speed insights scores for a single given page can be very volatile, and Google really does need to find a way to get round this. Mobile score is particularly erratic.I have just run 8 tests for the same page and got a mobile score of between 67 and 95. Now that's not a small fluctuation, it is enormous. Surely Google could find a way to avoid this; for instance by preloading a page into an entry chamber, then releasing it for insights analysis when and only when it is ready. It might take a bit longer to get a result, but probably not, as webmasters wouldn't need to retest the same page several times over in order to have a vague idea of the real result. The main fluctuation seems to be in blocking time, which is an external factor that probably has nothing to do with anything that the webmaster can change